# MySQL European Characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I can't figure this out for the life of me.

I have a query that pulls translations of elements on a page. So any number of 15 languages can appear on that page. When I start to add languages like Swedish anything that has a symbol such as `ö` results in the whole field returning a null string.

I've verified the encoding on the table and it claims it's using `UTF-8` but seeing as how this doesn't work I'm confused.

Here is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT
   form.form_id,
   elem.elem_type,
   elem.elem_name,
   elem.elem_format,
   elem.elem_required,
   trans.trans_label,`
   trans.trans_description,
   trans.trans_defaultValue,
   trans.trans_other,
   elem.elem_advancedcommand
FROM
   events_form form
LEFT JOIN
   events_form_elements elem
ON
   form.event_id = elem.event_id
INNER JOIN
   events_form_translations trans
ON
   elem.elem_id = trans.elem_id
INNER JOIN
   events_form_languages lang
ON
   trans.lang_id = lang.lang_id
WHERE 
   form.form_id = '{$formid}' AND lang.language = '{$language}'
ORDER BY
   elem.elem_sortorder
```

Now I tried to do something like:

`CONVERT(CAST(trans.trans_description as BINARY) USING latin1) as trans_description,`

To force it to covert the encoding but that doesn't yield a result at all.

After I get the result it's immediately json_encoded and returned to the user (Ajax Request). I DON'T think it's the json_encode as doing a `print_r` of the output array yields the same issues.

Also.. lastly, the system I'm building on is using xPDO so I'm not too sure if that's the issue either.

EDIT:
It seems that PHP IS returning a correct value or at least a value for example here is a `print_r` dump:

```
[trans_label] => Ditt f�rnamn?
[trans_description] => 
[trans_defaultValue] => First Name
```

So it seems that when my json_encode touches that string is when it turns the string to null.

Comment: Did you set the correct charset (in markup and as php-header) on the page & queried an "SET NAMES UTF8" before selecting the data?

Comment: You have a pretty complicated query there. Forgive me for asking the obvious: Is the data correct? Getting NULL values is not a typical character encoding problem.

Comment: @JoniSalonen Yes my SQL client pulls the correct info but when sending it through the code is when it returns with a NULL string.

Comment: I had similiar problem lately and what solved it is to "set names utf8" like first comment says.

Comment: What PHP array stores is not valid UTF-8. You solve the problem by forcing communication between MySQL and PHP to be UTF-8, using PDO - you can pass an array of options to the constructor, for this particular functionality it'd be `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your PDO connection string should specify the encoding. For example:

```
mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=test;charset=utf8
```

This controls the encoding that the *database driver* will use when it returns a result, and the encoding the driver assumes your queries are in. If you don't specify it, the default encoding will be used. Often the default is `latin1`.

You can confirm this by printing the hexadecimal representation of the data with [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) in PHP: the ö in förnamn is being returned as `f6`. If the text was encoded in UTF-8 you would obtain `c3b6`.

Comment: I hacked the CMS that I'm using to force using UTF8 as you suggested but I'm still getting output that looks like this: `Det h�r f�ltet kan inte l�mnas blankt.`

Comment: Ignore above: EDIT: That worked. The change I had made threw a server 500 but with a bit more tweaking it worked great. Thank you! You just ended a three day search.

Answer (score 3):

You said nothing about the encoding of your web pages.
Do you have that line in the `<head>` section of your page to force the encoding to UTF-8?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems endcoding letters to my native language *Icelandic* but ive found a mutual solution for all *utf8* letters.

> right after **mysql_select_db** and before **mysql_query** insert the following:

```
 mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8, 
 character_set_results=utf8, 
 character_set_client=utf8", $con);
```

Where $con is the connection to mysql

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is null after conversion due to incompatibility of data types.But showing European or Arabic characters on the page is quite simple.I had the same problem with Arabic language, but after few experiment its works fine now.

If you want to show those European characters on the page (jsp,php,html) first set the page encoding to UTF-8 like: -

> pageEncoding="utf-8"

And also you need some changes on your database connection class for utf-8 characters

Use the code below:-

> jdbc:mysql:your_ipaddress":3306/"+db+"?requireSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Hope it will help you.